# Micronaut: When using ExecutorService to asynchronously execute @Retryable method, "final" Exception is **not** logged as configured

Tags: micronaut

**TLDR**:
Exceptions thrown by code executed via injected ExecutorService are **not** logged via configured logger but appear on `System.err`.

**Background**:
Invocation of HTTP endpoint should trigger an asynchronously executed operation; the endpoint responds immediately (with status `202 Accepted`).

If asynchronous execution of this operation fails, it should get retried (applying `@Retryable` annotation).

If all retries are used up (because all retry attempts have failed), I encounter the behaviour mentioned above: The "final" Execption is **not** logged as configured, it seems to bypass all loggers, and appears on `System.err` (I've tested this by sending program's `System.err` output to separate file like this: `$ ./gradlew run 2> system.err`).

**Details**:
Controller's endpoint method:

```kotlin
@Controller
class Controller(private val injectedComponent: Component) {

  //@ExecuteOn(IO)
  @Get(value = "/async")
  fun asyncCall(
    @QueryValue
    message: String?
  ): HttpResponse<String> {
    injectedComponent.launchRetryThrowException(message ?: "DEFAULT ASYNC")
    return accepted()
  }

}
```

Simple component injected to Controller shown above:

```kotlin
@Singleton
open class ExceptionThrowingComponent(
  @Named("testing") private val callbackExecutorService: ExecutorService
) : Component {

  override fun launchRetryThrowException(message: String) {
    LOG.info("Launching with message '$message'.")
    callbackExecutorService.execute {
      retryThrowException(message)
    }
  }

  @Retryable(
    attempts = "2",
    multiplier = "1",
    delay = "1s"
  )
  open fun retryThrowException(message: String) {
    LOG.info("Going to throw RuntimeException with message '$message'.")
    throw RuntimeException(message)
  }

}
```

`ExecutorService` is injected by Micronaut using this `application.yml` config:

```yaml
micronaut:
  [...]
  executors:
    testing:
      type: cached
      core-pool-size: 2
```

Logging configuration in `logback.xml`:

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>CONFIGURED LOGGER: [%thread] - %msg%n
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Launching application with `$ ./gradlew run 2> system.err` followed by `$ curl localhost:8080/async` yields following log entries on console as expected:

```
CONFIGURED LOGGER: [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] - Launching with message 'DEFAULT ASYNC MESSAGE'
CONFIGURED LOGGER: [testing-executor-thread-1] - Going to throw RuntimeException with message 'DEFAULT ASYNC MESSAGE'
CONFIGURED LOGGER: [testing-executor-thread-1] - Going to throw RuntimeException with message 'DEFAULT ASYNC MESSAGE'
CONFIGURED LOGGER: [testing-executor-thread-1] - Going to throw RuntimeException with message 'DEFAULT ASYNC MESSAGE'
```

**But** "final" Exception (that appears with last retry) does **not** appear in log output, but is written to `System.err` (and redirected to file `system.err` because of `[...] 2> system.err`), ignoring logging configuration (message's prefix `CONFIGURED LOGGER` is missing):

```
$ cat system.err 
Exception in thread "testing-executor-thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: DEFAULT ASYNC MESSAGE
    at stacktrace.ExceptionThrowingComponent.retryThrowException(ExceptionThrowingComponent.kt:35)
    at stacktrace.$ExceptionThrowingComponent$Definition$Intercepted.$$access$$retryThrowException(Unknown Source)
    at stacktrace.$ExceptionThrowingComponent$Definition$Exec.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition$DispatchedExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition.java:378)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:128)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.AbstractInterceptorChain.proceed(AbstractInterceptorChain.java:174)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:45)
    at io.micronaut.aop.internal.intercepted.SynchronousInterceptedMethod.interceptResult(SynchronousInterceptedMethod.java:60)
    at io.micronaut.retry.intercept.DefaultRetryInterceptor.retrySync(DefaultRetryInterceptor.java:215)
    at io.micronaut.retry.intercept.DefaultRetryInterceptor.intercept(DefaultRetryInterceptor.java:120)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
    at stacktrace.$ExceptionThrowingComponent$Definition$Intercepted.retryThrowException(Unknown Source)
    at stacktrace.ExceptionThrowingComponent.launchRetryThrowException$lambda-0(ExceptionThrowingComponent.kt:24)
    at io.micronaut.scheduling.instrument.InvocationInstrumenterWrappedRunnable.run(InvocationInstrumenterWrappedRunnable.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Even addition of custom `TaskExceptionHandler` like explained at the end of [this chapter of Micronaut's documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#scheduling) doesn't change this behaviour.

Is this some kind of "logging leak" with Micronaut? Or have I missed something?

Thanks

Christian